# Php don't see mysql, mysqli and some other extensions

Tags: php

I installed apache web server, php and mysql. in configuration files everething is fine (both in php.ini and httpd.conf). The dlls in ext directory exist. But when I run phpinfo(), there is no mysql. What could be a problem?
My operating system Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64), installed php 5.2 in C:\Program Files\PHP folder.

Comment: No MySQL extension? No problem

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure on Windows, but I know on Linux you have to install the php-mysql package in order to use those extensions. That is the interface that allows PHP to talk to MySQL. I'd strongly advocate not using the mysql extension and going with mysqli or PDO (PHP Data Objects).

PDO Installation info - http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php

mysqli info - http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Hopefully you find that helpful

Comment: Did you install the MySQL Extension? You have to install the php extension in order to use mysqli functions

Answer (score 0):

I found how to handle this problem. First of all i had to add ;C:\Program Files\PHP to environment variable path and restart my computer. after restart everything started to work.